# How do I implement ActionListener with a non abstract class in Java

Tags: java, applet, awt, actionlistener, actionevent

Here is a code that i am trying to compile.all i get is error like this

s09_02 is not abstract and does not override abstract method
actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener.

So my question is, how can I implement ActionListener into my class (s09_02) if the class is not abstract?

Here is the entire code: (Because I have no idea where the problem could be)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class s09_02 extends Applet implements ActionListener{
public void init()
 {
  setLayout(null);
  setBackground(new Color(0,10,100));
 }
 public void paint(Graphics p){String t=null;
 int x,y,w,h,r,g,b;
 t=getParameter("xx");
 x=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("yy");
 y=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("ww");
 w=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("hh");
 h=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("rr");
 r=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("gg");
 g=Integer.parseInt(t);
 t=getParameter("bb");
 b=Integer.parseInt(t);
 p.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
 p.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
```

}
}

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="s09_02.class" width=400 height=400>
<param name="xx" value="25"><param name="yy" value="25">
<param name="ww" value="150"><param name="hh" value="150">
<param name="rr" value="0"><param name="gg" value="150">
<param name="bb" value="100">
</applet>
</body>
</html>


Also suggest me what changes should i make in this code so that code runs properly ??
Thanks...
```

Comment: Do what the compiler told you: implement the method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){}`.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){}` in you code as you are implementing `ActionListner`.

`ActionListner` is an `interface` so you need to override the abstract methods of `ActionListner`

If you are not using any event then remove the `implements ActionListner` from your code.

Comment: :Hey thanks for your suggestion..It worked for me by removing Action listener from my code....

Comment: @user3046211 Then do accept this answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the method

```
    @override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
//code that dose something
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html